# Jquery and basket js cache

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching

I am using Basket JS to cache some of my scripts, below is part of my code.

The main issue is that the plugin sequence loads but it does not execute, 
if I refresh the page then it executes.

However the plugin smoothscroll executes fine.

```
basket.require({ url: 'jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js'})
.then(function () {
basket.require({ url: 'js/vendor/jquery.sequence-min.js'},{ url: 'js/vendor/jquery.smooth-scroll.min.js'})
.then(function () {
req =basket.get('js/vendor/jquery.sequence-min.js');
scpt = req.data;
$('.seven a:link').smoothScroll();
basket.require({ url: 'js/vendor/s2.js'});
 });
});
```

s2.js :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var options = {
    nextButton: true,
    prevButton: true,
    pagination: true,
    animateStartingFrameIn: true,
    autoPlay: false

};

var mySequence = $("#sequence").sequence(options).data("sequence");

});
```

What have I tried?

If I load jquery normally and sequenceJs through Basket then the same thing happens.

If I load jquery and sequenceJs normally then all works fine.

I tried to load the cache version using jQuery Getscript and it wont inject the script.

```
req =basket.get('js/vendor/jquery.sequence-min.js');
scpt = req.data; // Use Getscript with scpt
```

The same thing happens with jQuery validate.

My guess it executes before the page loads? Thats why it fires the second time the page is refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

I am finding similar results, but I had thought that it was for a different reason. I find that on 2nd load they work for me, so I thought that basket.js is calling .then before it is done executing them.

```
 basket.clear();
 basket.require({ url: 'tooltips.js' })
        }).then(function () {
            req = basket.get('tooltips.js');
            alert(req);
```

Without the basket.clear() line it works on 2nd page load or refresh.
I contacted basket.js about this issue because I think it seems to be a problem in their promise system, or possibly in RSVPs. I am going to try some other branch of their code on github and see if anything there works for me.

Well, I thought about it again, and I decided you were right. It is an inline code issue.
I copied the inline code into another js file and put that into the then, and it alerted object object, and the code executed as expected. I am not certain what I want to do yet though, as I don't want to have too many js files.

```
 basket.clear();
 basket.require({ url: 'tooltips.js' })
        }).then(function () {
            basket.require(a file with the same code in it instead of inline
```

this works.